# play video clip in windows c++ app

Tags: c++, video

Im currently using [wxMediaCtrl](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_media_ctrl.html) to play videos in my app. The api is unfortunately a little buggy, and doesn't playback all media types i need to support (e.g. wmv).

I am wondering if there is an alternative c++ api, that will allow me to do this. I am currently just concerned with supporting windows.

What do people normally use to embedd video in their apps? Also i need to be in control, i.e. tell the video, where to play in time, pause/stop, i dont need any shuttle controls, as i have my own.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wxMediaControl uses DirectShow on Windows, it should be able to play wmv files. If you can play a media file with [GraphStudio](http://blog.monogram.sk/janos/tools/monogram-graphstudio/), you should be able to play it with wxMediaControl.
If not, you need to install the proper video codecs. Have you tried installing [FFDShow](http://ffdshow-tryout.sourceforge.net/)?

You can try [Video Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd695342%28VS.85%29.aspx), and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd693083%28VS.85%29.aspx) is a sample on how you can play a video file.

If you want something without DirectShow, you can take a look at [VLC ActiveX](http://wiki.videolan.org/ActiveX).

As a word of caution regarding the use of GPL plugins (FFDShow or VLC ActiveX) in non-GPL applications you should read [this](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html#NFUseGPLPlugins).

Comment: Ok so i can play wmv files with GraphStudio but not wxMediaControl. How come?

Comment: I guess you found a bug in wxMediaControl. The wxWidgets guys should be able to be of more assistance: http://www.wxwidgets.org/support/

Answer (score 1):

Qt uses [Phonon](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/phonon-overview.html) for cross-platform media *playback*. On Windows Phonon utilizes DirectShow, so it can play anything Windows can (.wmv). It has all the capability you mentioned. It's also very easy to implement and use. I recommend highly.